# How to load local JavaScript libraries in Github Pages?

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, github-pages, internal-link

I recently deployed my website to GitHub Pages - https://max-stevenson.github.io/my-year-in-books/

I have a two local JavaScript libraries (jQuery and swiped-events) downloaded and within the following directory: `src/public/js/lib`.

In my `index.html` file at the root directory, I am linking to the two libraries like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/src/public/js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/src/public/js/lib/swiped-events.js"></script>
```

But when I access the page on GitHub Pages I get the following errors:

```
GET https://max-stevenson.github.io/src/public/js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
GET https://max-stevenson.github.io/src/public/js/lib/swiped-events.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

When I run a local instance on my machine via a node express server and visit the site at localhost:3000, everything works great.

Can anyone please advise me where I'm going wrong and how to correctly reference my scripts so that they are loaded in GitHub Pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/my-year-in-books/scr/js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script
```

Or:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scr/public/js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script
```

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="./scr/public/js/lib/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>` worked perfectly thanks